# Como dejar de buscar en un array al encontrar un elemento?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:
Un restaurante nos ha encargado una aplicación para colocar a los clientes en
sus mesas. En una mesa se pueden sentar de 0 (mesa vacía) a 4 comensales
(mesa llena). Cuando llega un cliente se le pregunta cuántos son. De momento
el programa no está preparado para colocar a grupos mayores a 4, por tanto,
si un cliente dice por ejemplo que son un grupo de 6, el programa dará el
mensaje “Lo siento, no admitimos grupos de 6, haga grupos de 4
personas como máximo e intente de nuevo”. Para el grupo que llega,
se busca siempre la primera mesa libre (con 0 personas). Si no quedan mesas
libres, se busca donde haya un hueco para todo el grupo, por ejemplo si el
grupo es de dos personas, se podrá colocar donde haya una o dos personas.
Inicialmente, las mesas se cargan con valores aleatorios entre 0 y 4. Cada
vez que se sientan nuevos clientes se debe mostrar el estado de las mesas.
Los grupos no se pueden romper aunque haya huecos sueltos suficientes.

El problema que tengo es que busco una mesa vacia vale, comparo e ingreso la cantidad de personas.... en ese momento se supone que deberia dejar de buscar mesas vacia, pero el programa me sigue buscando mesas vacia y ingresa personas, no encuentro la manera de que el programa se salga del ciclo o deje de buscar mesas cuando haya encontra ya la primera... espero hacerme entender.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);

    int mesa[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int ocupacion [] = {3,2,0,2,4,1,0,2,1,1};
    int cant;
    int aux;

    do{
        System.out.println("Bienvenidos a mi restaurante");    
        System.out.println("Cuantos son?: (Introduzca -1 para salir del programa)");
        cant = entrada.nextInt();

        if (cant == -1){
            break;
        }else if (cant >4 ){
            System.out.println("Lo sentimos no admitimos grupos de:" + cant);
        } // Esto se puede utilizar mas adelante
    } while(cant>4);
    aux = cant;

    while (aux>0){
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if(ocupacion [i] ==0){
                System.out.println("Por favor, sientese en la mesa numero: "+ mesa[j]);
                ocupacion [i] = cant;
                break;
            }

       /* CODIGO INCOMPLETO POR LOS MOMENTOS UwU 
            else if ((ocupacion [i] + cant) < 5){break;
                System.out.println("Lo sentimos, tendra que compartir mesa: ");
                ocupacion [i] = ocupacion [i] + cant;
                break;
            }*/
            j++;
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(ocupacion [i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ummm un restaurante que funcione así me parece que quebrará pronto, si yo llego con 6 personas el restuarante no puede decirme que no, que sólo hay mesas para un máximo de 4 personas, pero bueno, el dueño sabrá... :) En cuanto al problema en sí, creo que sería mejor manejarlo mediante dos clases. Una clase `Mesa` y otra clase `Grupo`, así controlas el estado de las mesas de forma más organizada... Lo que no entiendo bien es si en ese restaurante mezclan a la gente, o sea, que yo llego con 6 personas y colocan a 4 de las 6 en una mesa y a las otras 2 en otra mesa donde previamente había otros 2

Comment: no puedo usar clases....tiene que ser con arreglos y estructuras ciclicas. asi lo mando el prof :'v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi estimado, el break que pones es solo para salir de ciclo for, el while siempre se queda iterando, por lo tanto tu ciclo while está ciclaco, puedes idear muchas maneras para terminar tu while, la más simple y rápida podría ser que cuando encuentre una mes vacía, pongas tu variable aux con valor cero, de esa manera ya no dará otra vuelta y por lo cual, ya no leera tu array nuevamente,

```
while (aux>0){
    int j = 0;    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(ocupacion [i] ==0){
            System.out.println("Por favor, sientese en la mesa numero: "+ mesa[j]);
            ocupacion [i] = cant;
            //Algo así, esto ya podría ser cómo lo quieras tratar
           //pero debes de cambiar el estado de esta variable para que te rompa el ciclo.                           
           aux=0;
           break;
        }

 /* CODIGO INCOMPLETO POR LOS MOMENTOS UwU 
   else if ((ocupacion [i] + cant) < 5){break;
   System.out.println("Lo sentimos, tendra que compartir mesa: ");
    ocupacion [i] = ocupacion [i] + cant;
    break;
     }*/
     j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Who muchas gracias amigos (Y) efectivametne es como dices... supongo que me hace falta mas practica.

Answer (score 0):

Te faltó hacer que corte el segundo while me parece: 'while (aux>0)'
...'aux' sigue siendo un número mayor que cero y el 'break' creo que corta sólo el ciclo 'for'.